# What are SQL Server data-types mapped to by default in ADO.NET?

Tags: .net, sql-server, types, ado.net, sql-types

I need a list of all the SQL types and their .NET equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729) post, for SQL Server types.

For other data providers see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e5xt97a).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list for .NET 3.5 / ADO.NET / SqlClient provider:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

In addition, when dealing with ADO.NET parameters, keep in mind that you can specify varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) by using -1 as the length.

Comment: The OP didn't specify a framework version, and it isn't hard from the page i posted to find your way to other versions. Hardly worth a down vote.